# Can Yii2 sql query select custom column with values from the model attribute/function (not in DB)?

Tags: sql, yii2

Using Yii2, I need to have run an SQL query with the additional field that is calculated and stored in the model/method in the model, and will be used in the WHERE section later on.

For example:
In my model, I have a method that calculates some value for me, let's call it getCalculatedAttribute(). Say it will return a number.

Can I do something like `` SELECT *, $this->getCalculatedAttribute() AS calculatedAttribute FROM `object_table` WHERE calculatedAttribute = 2; `` using Yii2 Query?

Yii2 Query example like `Object::find()->where(['calculatedAttribute' => 2]);`

I don't know how to add the custom attribute with alias.
I've tried googling around but with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: No, you can't run PHP code in SQL query context.

Comment: You cannot execute SQL queries with PHP in it. Thus, you could concatenate this `SELECT *, $this->getCalculatedAttribute() AS calculatedAttribute FROM object_table WHERE calculatedAttribute = 2;` in PHP and then use this string to query your database.

Comment: No you cannot do that. You need to either have a select statement or a join to another query. This will allow sorting and filtering and you will no longer need the calculatedAttribute function because the data will be supplied by the query (and a LOT faster)